# How to get the data from the c3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3

I am developing from the c3.js using reusable charts in d3.js,but unable to get the data from the array of objects,i tried for the given format of the code.

```
    var chart=c3.generate({
          data:{
              json:[
             {"key":[2000],"value":100},{"key":[2001],"value":200},{"key":[2003],"value":300},{"key":[2004],"value":400},{"key":[2005],"value":500},{"key":[2006],"value":600},{"key":[2007],"value":700}
                      ],
              keys:{x:'key[0]',
                    value:'value',
              }
   },
             axis: {
          x: {
            type: "category"
          }
        }

})
```

Answer (score 5):

```
chart.data('value')[0].values[0].value
```

c3 documentation [here](http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-data)

check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evvajoLj/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this what you are going for:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
        data:{
              json:[
             {"key":2000,"value":100},{"key":2001,"value":200},
             {"key":2003,"value":300},{"key":2004,"value":400},
             {"key":2005,"value":500},{"key":2006,"value":600},
             {"key":2007,"value":700}
              ],
              keys:{
                  x: "key",
                  value:['value']
              }
    },
    axis: {
          x: {
            type: "category"
          }
        }
});
```

I'm not sure why you would have the key for a data point be an array (perhaps you want to swap the keys and values?), but here is a basic key, value line graph, which is what I think you are going for.

checkout out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evvajoLj/8/) adapted from Sikandar Tamboli's answer